# htm5mode with parameters doesn't work for me

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, location-provider

The first hand, this is my code:

config app:

```
promoApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider.
        when('/home',{
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }).
        when('/web',{
            templateUrl: 'views/web.html',
            controller: 'WebController'
        }).
        when('/portfolio',{
            templateUrl: 'views/portfolio.html'
        }).
        when('/game',{
            templateUrl: 'views/game.html'
        }).
        when('/contact',{
            templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactController'
        }).
        when('/admin',{
            templateUrl: 'views/admin.html',
            controller: 'AdminController'
        }).
        when('/blog_admin',{
            templateUrl: 'views/blog_admin.html',
            controller: 'BlogAdminController'
        }).
        when('/blog_edit', {
            templateUrl: 'views/blog_edit.html',
            controller: 'BlogEditController'
        }).
        when('/blog_edit/:blogId', {
            templateUrl: 'views/blog_edit_post.html',
            controller: 'BlogEditPostController'
        }).
        when('/blog',{
            templateUrl: 'views/blog.html',
            controller: 'BlogController'
        }).
        when('/blog/:blogId',{
            templateUrl: 'views/blog_post.html',
            controller: 'BlogPostController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
    }]);
```

my controller BlogPostController:

```
blog.controller('BlogPostController',['$scope','$http','$upload','$routeParams','$sce',function($scope,$http,$upload,$routeParams,$sce){
        $scope.blogId = $routeParams.blogId;
        $scope.$upload = $upload.upload({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'edit.php',
            data: {'title': $scope.blogId}
        }).success(function(data){
            if(data.error){
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
            }else{
                $scope.post = data;
                $scope.pastToPlainText = $sce.trustAsHtml;
            }
        });

        $http.get('backend/muestra.php').success(function(data){
            if(data.error){
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
            }else{
                $scope.entradas = data;
            }
        }).error(function(){
            $scope.resultMessage = "Se ha producido un error al consultar con la base de datos";
        });
    }]);
```

my blog.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 position-panel-blog hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <div class="panel panel-primary margin-index">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Entradas recientes</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div ng-repeat="entrada in entradas | limitTo: 5">
                        {{$index + 1}}. <a ng-href="/blog/{{entrada.title}}" class="link-blog">{{entrada.title}}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Nuestros servicios web</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <img src="images/que-ofrecemos/portada_web.jpg" alt="Nuestros servicios web" class="image-anuncio">
                    <div class="acceder">
                        <a href="#/web" class="btn btn-primary">Accede ahora</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-position col-lg-8" ng-repeat="entrada in entradas">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="margin-content-blog">
                    <a ng-href="/blog/{{entrada.title}}" class="link-blog"><h1 class="format-title-blog">{{entrada.title}}</h1></a>
                    <div ng-bind-html="pastToPlainText(entrada.text)" class="text-blog"></div>
                    <slick infinite="false" dots="true" slides-to-show="3" slides-to-scroll="1">
                        <div ng-repeat="image in entrada.images track by $index">
                            <img src="{{image}}" alt="Imagen de la entrada {{entrada.title}}" class="image-post img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    </slick>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <!-- Inserta esta etiqueta en la sección "head" o justo antes de la etiqueta "body" de cierre. -->
                            <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
                                {lang: 'es'}
                            </script>
                            <!-- Inserta esta etiqueta donde quieras que aparezca Botón Compartir. -->
                            <div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When click to go to the post, the template blog_post.html is loaded according to $route.current.templateUrl but the browser shows the same content than blog.html and doesn't show the content of blog_post.html template. Without the html5mode, this works correctly and there aren't problems. Maybe html5mode doesn't work well with the parameters links (/blog_edit/:blogId). Below I explain this better with images.

With html5mode enable:

1. I'm in blog menu and I'm going to click in a post: (the template is blog.html)
   [image]
2. When click on post, the current router change the template to blog_post.html but the browser shows me the same template blog.html:
   [image]

With html5mode disable:

1. When I'm in blog.html template and I'm going to click on post:
   [image]
2. When I have already clicked the post. Now it shows me the blog_post.html template correctly:
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

To support direct links to URLs created in HTML5 mode you need URL rewriting on the server. E.g. via `mod_rewrite` if you are using Apache.

From [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

> **Server side**
>
> Using this [HTML5] mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to [the] entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)

If you already are doing this, please also provide relevant server configuration.

Comment: Hello @divideandconquer.se. This is my .htaccess file http://pastebin.com/AiLsa2j6 . Is there something that I have to do in the sever configuration?

Comment: @Dominuskernel sorry for the lack of response. The .htaccess looks correct. But maybe you should try to strip out the Prerender stuff and make it work without?